# find: list all directories except those with numbers in their names and their children

Tags: find, regular-expression

I am running the following to find all directories without a number in them (not including the original path):

```
find /path/2/directory -type d -name '[!0-9]*'
```

The problem is that it finds directories that are subdirectories of directories that have numbers.

Example:

```
/path/2/directory/20160303/backup
```

or even

```
/path/2/directory/backup20160303a/backup
```

Is there any way to prevent find from returning such directories?

I cannot solve this problem by limiting the depth, the depth can vary.

Example:

```
/path/2/directory/subdirectory/20160303/backup
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `-prune` to ignore those directories:

```
find /path/to/directory -name '*[0-9]*' -prune -o -type d -print
```

though if you're on a `gnu` setup you may want to use the `C` locale when running the above, see Stéphane's comment below.

Comment: This one worked without any tweaking.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Note that on GNU systems at least, that will still include directories whose name contains digits _and_ an invalid character. You could fix the locale to C to avoid that.

Comment: Note that the first `-type d` is not necessary here.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas - yup, thanks for the heads up ! I assume that gnu specific behaviour is a known bug ? @Mocking - it doesn't need tweaking because it uses the right pattern with `-name` as opposed to Anthon's solution, see my comments under his answer.

Comment: Not really a bug, `*` is 0 or more _characters_, so doesn't match non-characters. Behaviour differs across implementations. Same as for regexps, `.` matches a character, so `.*` doesn't match across non-characters in most implementations. When it comes to shells `*` and `?` in practice do match bytes that don't form part of valid characters (even though at least for `?` that's against POSIX (and something that needs to be addressed in the spec).

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want find to descent beyond a certain match you should use `-prune` and not e.g. `-path` or filtering the output of `find` with `grep -v`

To test things out make an environment with some extra files and subdirs, so you can check your `find` not to display unwanted material:

```
mkdir -p tmp/2/abc/def
touch tmp/2/abc/def/file1
mkdir -p tmp/2/abc/9876/xyz
touch tmp/2/abc/9876/xyz/file2
tree tmp/
```

gives:

```
tmp
└── 2
    └── abc
        ├── 9876
        │   └── xyz
        │       └── file2
        └── def
            └── file1
```

If you do `find tmp/2/abc \! -path "*[0-9]*"` as suggested by @terdon, the output will be empty, because `-path` doesn't just take into account the directories starting below `abc` but the whole path, which includes `2`. So that is not what you want.

If you do `find tmp/2/abc -type d | grep -vE '/[0-9-]+(/|$)'`, as suggested by @cas, you'll find that it doesn't print anything either, again because it matcheds not just the files down from where you're searching but also the directory named `2`. Apart from that this would require find to first walk the whole tree under `9876` and if there are a few hundred thousand items there the walking (and filtering) will take a noticable amount of time.

If you do:

```
find tmp/2/abc -type d -name '[!0-9]*' -print
```

you will find that the output includes the path `tmp/2/abc/9876/xyz`. To get
rid of that cut off what you don't want with `-prune`:

```
find tmp/2/abc -type d -name '[!0-9]*' -print -o -name '[0-9]*' -prune
```

which gives:

```
tmp/2/abc
tmp/2/abc/def
```

you can slightly improve the on the efficiency of that by swapping the pruning and printing which is what @don_cristti did in his enhancement of this answer.

Comment: I am aware of maxdepth but the depth can vary.  Thanks though.

Comment: @Mocking I noticed, you have to prune matching directories that have numbers, I updated the answer

Comment: I'm gonna upvote this since you posted prune first but it didn't work for some cases even when I tweaked it.  @don_crissti had a copy and paste working one.  Thanks for the help though.  Edit: Nevermind I don't have enough rep.

Comment: fwiw, your post and terdon's weren't working OK when I posted mine and they're still not working fine - at least on my setup; terdon's has the flaws you mentioned and it prints also regular file names and yours doesn't work as expected - I had to replace `-name '[!0-9]*'` with `! -name '*[0-9]*'` (and use the same `'*[0-9]*'` for the second `-name`) to make it work.

Comment: without details of your setup it is easy to claim they are not working fine and that a minor tweak is necessary, that is why I included my test environment in my answer and pointed out the issues with the others.

Comment: Saying "at least on my setup" was my way of being polite... there's no need for any details and I don't _claim_ anything - I just can't explain in a comment block how pattern matching works - your answer does not work and will not work as expected because you're doing the wrong pattern matching.

Comment: "they're still not working fine" reads like a (unsubstantiated) claim to me. No need to explain if you can't. Of course an example of something matched that shouldn't, or vv.,would have been sufficient.

Comment: come on man, I could add an explanation to my post if this is still unclear: you do realise that your `-name '[!0-9]*'` means _match any names that start with a non-digit char followed by anything_ (anything could also be digits/numbers) ? which is why your solution works only with the particular directory tree sample you used but fails otherwise ?

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for `-path`:

```
   -path pattern
          File  name matches shell pattern pattern.  The metacharacters do
          not treat `/' or `.' specially; so, for example,
                    find . -path "./sr*sc"
          will print an entry for a directory called `./src/misc' (if  one
          exists).
```

It searches the entire path of each file/directory for the given pattern. So, if you have a directory structure like this:

```
$ tree
.
├── 111
│   └── foo
│       └── bar
├── bar
│   └── foo
│       └── baz
└── foo
    └── 111
        └── bar

9 directories, 0 files
```

You can use `find` like this:

```
$ find /path/to/directory/ \! -path "*[0-9]*" 
.
./foo
./bar
./bar/foo
./bar/foo/baz
```

Or, with GNU `find`:

```
find /path/to/directory/ -not -path "*[0-9]*"
```

Since this will have to descend into each directory to check its name, it will be significantly slower on large directory trees than [@Anthon's solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/267499/22222) with prune. If you don't have thousands of directories, though, it should be fine.

Comment: This would have been almost perfect, the problem I think is that my original /path/to/directory has a number in it.  This is my fault for not clarifying the problem, I edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to use `grep` (or `awk` or `sed` or `perl` etc) to remove such directories from `find`'s output:

```
find /path/to/directory -type d | grep -vE '/[0-9-]+(/|$)'
```

Note: I've included `-` in the character class because dated directories are sometimes YYYY-MM-DD rather than just YYYYMMDD

Comment: Of course it might be horrible expensive (in time) to first descend into subdirectories that you know you can ignore upfront